# Multiple conditions in a for loop?

Tags: julia, multiple-conditions

I am trying to figure out what this pseudocode would be in Julia code:

Pseudocode:

```
for (i = 0; (i < 32) && (array[i] ≠ nil); i += 1) do
            result := merge(array[i], result)
            array[i] := nil
```

The multiple conditions seem to trip me up. I don't know how to format it in Julia. If anyone knows how I would appreciate it. I am new to the language.

Comment: Are you trying to get all the elements of array that are not equal to `nil`? Is `nil` a particular value or is it of type `Nothing`? It looks like you're growing `result` inside the loop which typically is not performant. If you really are trying to extract the elements of the array that are not `nothing` then just use `[ x for x in array if !isnothing(x) ]`

Comment: For such situations I would use `while` loop in Julia.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it in Julia. For example, you can use `break` statement

```
for i in 1:32          # in Julia we usually start numbering from 1
   array[i] == nothing && break
   result = merge(array[i], result)
   array[i] = nothing
end
```

or `while` loop

```
i = 1
while i <= 32 && array[i] != nothing
   result = merge(array[i], result)
   array[i] = nothing
   i += 1
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do the looping and put the conditional inside:

```
nil = nothing  #or any other sentinel value
for i in 1:32 #for i in eachindex(array) 
  if array[i] != nil #if cond1 & cond2 & cond3... &condn
    result = merge(result, array[i]) 
    array[i] = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: That's not the same thing though, unless you add an `else` with `break`.